# EROFS: read-only file system, open

Tags: reactjs, linux

I use Linux mint OS
I get this error whenever i try to run the code "git push".

**error code after running git commit -a**

[image]

Also when I try to start my sever I get a similar error also.

**error message after running yarn start**

[image]

Comment: Can you run `mount` and paste the output somewhere?

Comment: You are on a read-only filesystem.

Comment: How do i change it from being a read-only filesystem to a read-write filesystem.

Comment: That depends on **why** the file system is read-only.

Comment: Did you install the OS? Is it a live image?

Comment: @JCWasmx86 ok let me try that

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano i installed the OS

Comment: @JCWasmx86 here's the url to the pastebin. https://pastebin.com/7XwWv1Va